# Unexpected token " " space in WebStorm

Tags: css, webstorm

I just started using JetBrains WebStorm, and it is flagging all blocks of code in the following style with unexpected token errors.

```css
.container.\32 25\25 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 125%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

In all cases, the unexpected token is in the same position; the space between .\32 and 25\25.

Would anybody have an idea as to why this happens? The code runs smoothly on all browsers.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but what is `25\25`

Comment: Can you provide the HTML snippet? This looks like a weird way to write a custom class name/tag

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for the explanation .. always something new to learn or become aware of :)

Comment: @MrLister If I understand correctly, for the case above that would be **.container.\32\25\25**? I can confirm that the error message is removed when in this format.

Comment: @MrLister Yep, the errors disappear, and the code works fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in this case seems to be with WebStorm, which flags things as errors that are not errors. The escaped format in your source sample is perfectly fine; it refers to a class named `"225%"`. The W3C validator doesn't return errors; the browsers respond as they should; so it's just WebStorm.
See [Using character escapes in markup and CSS](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#cssescapes).

In short, CSS has the ability to escape characters in a hex format, so that you can refer to a class name that begins with a "2" by writing `.\32` instead of `.2`.
(In CSS, you can't write `.2` if you mean a class, because `.2` would always be interpreted as the number 0.2, no matter where it occurs. Don't ask me why.)
And the space after the `.\32` is a delimiter for the escape code, that says the number ends there, so the following numbers are actual digits in the class name; up to the `\25` which denotes a percent sign.

Note that you'll only need the delimiter if the following characters can be hex digits. If the next character is, for example, another `\`, there's no need for the space at all.

And there's the solution to your issue: if you want no space to appear in the whole class definition, you can escape all the characters in it, so the class becomes `\32\32\35\25` and therefore the entire selector becomes `.container.\32\32\35\25`.

Hope this helps!